# Error javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()

Tags: tomcat, java-8

Tengo dos servidores con las siguientes características:

- Oracle Linux Server release 7
- Java jre1.8.0_221
- apache-tomcat-8.5.54

Ambos servidores tienen declaradas las mismas variables de entorno y configuraciones de tomcat.

Tengo un proyecto Maven con el cual genero un .war que despliego en los tomcat. Todas las librerías y dependencias las tengo definidas en el pom.xml del proyecto.

En concreto la que necesitaria que falla:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

La conexión a BBDD esta definida en el context.xml del mismo modo en ambos tomcat, y el applicationContext.xml tiene definido este código acerca dela parte que falla.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.XXXX.XXXXX.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

En uno de los servidores me despliega correctamente el aplicativo, y en el otro me da el siguiente error que veo en los logs del tomcat:

14-May-2020 16:20:10.315 INFO [localhost-startStop-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
14-May-2020 16:20:10.457 INFO [localhost-startStop-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14-May-2020 16:20:10.992 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getSharedCacheMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:104)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation(LogHelper.java:51)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:196)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:177)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
                ... 25 more
14-May-2020 16:20:10.994 INFO [localhost-startStop-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

¿Alguna idea de porque puede darse el fallo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente estaba incorrectamente creada la imagen del servidor, al reiniciarlo y redesplegar se solucionó el problema.